# remove stroke in postscript

Tags: postscript, stroke

I have script in ps

```
%!
%% Example 4

/box0{ 
newpath 56 257 moveto 
0 -198 rlineto 
284 0 rlineto 
0 198 rlineto 
-284 0 rlineto 

closepath } def 

/Times-Roman findfont
32 scalefont
setfont


box0
gsave
/test{

(Example 4) true charpath stroke

} def
test
showpage
```

and it shows square, how can I remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /box0{...} def defines a function which draws a box.

```
/box0{ newpath 56 257 moveto 0 -198 rlineto 284 0 rlineto 0 198 rlineto
       -284 0 rlineto closepath } def
```

The box0 invoked the `/box0` function and draws a box, but does not fill it or stroke it, so the path remains part of the currentpath. The closepath connects from the point reached by the `-284 0 rlineto` which happens to be the starting point 58,257. You then start some text from the baseline of the text, which places the baseline of the text on the top of the box. `charpath` adds the path of the text onto the path of the box. The `stroke` strokes both the charpath and the box.

If you don't want the box, remove the `box0`.

The gsave shouldn't be there or should have a matching grestore.

Comment: But I need stroke text and I want to place them on image so I need to move cursor to the area, and then need to place text, there might have been case, I dint clear myself, but this a actual case

Comment: Assuming that box zero is the only place the position exists, `box0 currentpoint newpath moveto /test{....` The currentpoint will capture the location of the box, the newpath will delete the box, the moveto will restore the box's point, then you can define the text and stroke it.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably removing the call to box0 will remove the square. I take it you didn't code this PostScript program yourself ?

Comment: But I need stroke text and I want to place them on image so I need to move cursor to the area, and then need to place text, there might have been case, I dint clear myself, but this a actual case

Comment: Then simply 'moveto' the point where you want the text. Or as Fred F says above, execute the box0 routine, capture the current point, use newpath to eliminate the path constructed by box0 and then 'moveto' the point that you captured. The 'box0' routine doesn't move the current point, it creates a path which starts and ends at a given point.